# apache2 on ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.2, ubuntu-10.04

does apache2 from apt-get on ubuntu come with sendfile pre-installed?

Answer (score 1):

Since that is part of Apache's core since [version 2.0.44](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#enablesendfile) and later it is available.